# How can I remove duplicate values of a list of tuples based on max value?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples that looks like this:

```
[('John', 53, "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 62.4, "Yes", "Yes"), ('Amy', 46, "No", "No", "No", "No", 52.2, "No", "No"), ('John', 53, "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 65, "No", "No")]
```

I want to remove duplicates and only return with max value for index 6 so it looks something like this:

```
[('Amy', 46, "No", "No", "No", "No", 52.2, "No", "No"), ('John', 53, "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 65, "Yes", "Yes")]
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is the key for detecting duplicates, only the first index? Or the first two?

Comment: I want to remove duplicate names (index 0), but i will keep the one with the largest value for index 6 of the tuple. So for John, he has 2 tuples. I only want to keep the number 65 because it is bigger than 62.4. And Amy do not have duplicate so i will still keep it in as well.

Comment: why are the last 2 indices changing from "no", "no" to "yes", "yes" ?

Comment: they are different responses by the user

Answer (score 1):

With a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for item in l:
  name = item[0]
  if not name in d or d[name][6] < item[6]:
    d[name] = item
    
new_l = list(d.values())
```

If you need to preserve order:

```
new_l = []
names = []

for item in l:
    name = item[0]
    if not name in names: 
        new_l.append(item)
        names.append(name)
    else:
        i = names.index(name)
        if new_l[i][6] < item[6]:
            new_l[i] = item
```

Comment: is there a way to preserve the order of appearance for new_l?
such that John will appear after Amy since John with 65 came after Amy in the original l.

Comment: See my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby` and the `max` function. `operator.itemgetter` helps with getting values and you'll need the data sorted as well:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

get_name, get_val = itemgetter(0), itemgetter(6)

data = [('John', 53, "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 62.4, "Yes", "Yes"), ('Amy', 46, "No", "No", "No", "No", 52.2, "No", "No"), ('John', 53, "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 65, "No", "No")]

res = [max(g, key=get_val) for _, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=get_name), get_name)]
```

---

```
[('Amy', 46, 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 52.2, 'No', 'No'), ('John', 53, 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 65, 'No', 'No')]
```

Without imports:

```
data = [('John', 53, "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 62.4, "Yes", "Yes"), ('Amy', 46, "No", "No", "No", "No", 52.2, "No", "No"), ('John', 53, "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 65, "No", "No")]

data.sort(key=lambda x:x[6], reverse=True)
seen = set(); seen_add = seen.add
res = [t for t in data if not ((n:=t[0]) in seen or seen_add(n))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` sorting the list of tuples on names to solve what you have explained, *but your expected output is anyways not correct*:

```py
>>> [max(v, key=lambda x:x[6]) for _,v in groupby(sorted(lst,
                                                         key=lambda x:x[0]), 
                                                  key=lambda x:x[0])]
Out[12]: 
[('Amy', 46, 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 52.2, 'No', 'No'),
 ('John', 53, 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 65, 'No', 'No')]
```

Comment: what about other ways without using any libraries like itertools?

Comment: itertools is a builtin library.

Answer (score 0):

If the final list's order doesn't matter, first sort by element 6

```
responses = [
    ('John', 53, "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 62.4, "Yes", "Yes"),
    ('Amy', 46, "No", "No", "No", "No", 52.2, "No", "No"),
    ('John', 53, "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 65, "No", "No")
]
responses.sort(key=lambda e: e[6], reverse=True)
```

then filter only non-duplicates

```
filtered_responses = []
used_names = []
for r in responses:
    if r[0] not in used_names:
        filtered_responses.append(r)
        used_names.append(r[0])
```

Comment: This raises a `NameError` in the `if` statement and will return the min value not the max if the error is fixed.

Comment: @Jab fixed, code solves the problem now